# Is regex search possible in spoltlight?

Tags: macos, spotlight

It seems that there is no way to search file content using regex by spotlight. Is it so? Thanks.

https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Carbon/Conceptual/SpotlightQuery/Concepts/QueryFormat.html

Comment: Please see [this](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/3268/how-to-use-regex-with-spotlight) and [this](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/3268/how-to-use-regex-with-spotlight) and see if it answers your questions.

Comment: As you suspect from the Apple documentation, general [regular expressions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression) are not supported in Spotlight queries. See the linked duplicate question for possible approaches and work arounds.

Comment: Please answer yes or no. These posts were so old and don't provide a clear answer of yes or no. At least I don't see the answers there were conclusive. My takehome message were no.

Comment: A yes or no answer requires agreeing a definition of *regular expression*. The term regular expression is often conflated with Perl Compatible Regular Expressions (PCRE). In the Apple documentation you linked to, Spotlights own form of regular expression is defined and it comes no-where close to the power or scope of PCRE. Does this help?