# How to search for .zip files instead of all compressed files?

Tags: macos, spotlight, search

How do you search for a file of a **specific type** in OS X Yosemite?  I cannot seem to find any instructions on how to do this.

In the Finder search I enter: `kind:zip`

But it returns **all** compressed files.  I only want zip files - so this [AD post](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/602/how-can-i-search-a-specific-type-of-file-in-mac) does not help me much.  All the solutions either use bash, or I cannot find the options they refer to.

Comment: @patrix Typing "kind:zip" in the Search Field is just **plain text** not **source code** and should not be shown as `kind:zip` and why I originally edited it among the other edits.  Why did you change it back?  I set it bold to differentiate however it could just be plain as it's plainly evident by syntax it was something typed.

Comment: @user3439894 This is probably not the last discussions we are going to have about formatting on AD, feel free to join in on http://meta.apple.stackexchange.com/questions/2361/why-was-my-edit-removing-code-formatting-reverted :-) In a nutshell: I see a significant difference between putting emphasis on some words and marking text which the user can/should type in. It is (at least on AD) quite common to use code formatting for the latter. If you want to discuss this further, please use the Meta site or the chat room.

Comment: I'm going to point this at the existing search question. With some of the great answers here, I'm also considering merging the answers. Ask on [meta] if anyone has strong opinions on the close/merge options.

Comment: @bmike - I reference that post in my post - it does not answer this specific question.  It answers it too generally and most are BASH solutions, not a Finder solution.  The answer checked here actually answers this specific question.  Thank you for your consideration on not considering this a duplicate, but more of an extension.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Open a new finder window and type "zip" in the search. Select "Zip archive" in "kinds".

> [image]

You can also just type out `kind:.zip` and press enter and you'll get the appropriate filter:

[image]

Note - omitting the . after the : results in many compressed files and not just those with .zip extension or literal conformance to [that specification](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zip_(file_format)).

Comment: This is the answer I was looking for - Thank you.  BTW, you may want to mention that *it takes a few moments before the dropdown options are displayed*.  That threw me for a while because I was not seeing it, and exited the search bar before it displayed.

Comment: @And yes, it does take a second or a half of a second :)

Comment: @AndroidAddict I've added a way to accelerate the typing and also linked this more strongly to [7 How Can I Search A Specific Type of File in Mac?](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/602/)

Comment: I'm confused.  The `kind.zip` returns JARs too from the image that you posted.  Whereas selecting the zip archive in the dropdown limits results to just `zip` files.

Comment: @And It was an edit from bmike. Read the answer to the end.

Answer (score 3):

Type <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> on Finder and you will see the search bar. By default appears **Kind** is **Any**. Replace **Kind** with **File Extension** (you can find it under **Others...**), then you can type **zip** in the field and you will have the results immediately.

Additionally if you feel confortable with the Terminal, you can use the following command:

```
find . -name "*.zip"
```

Comment: I appreciate the BASH solution (which I already know) - I want to learn how to do this through Finder if possible.

Answer (score 3):

You can directly search for **zip** files by entering:

```
kMDItemFSName:.zip
```

or even better:

```
kMDItemKind:"Zip"
```

into Spotlight Search in Finder.

To get more `kMD*` keywords make `mdls /path/to/file` in Terminal to list them.

[Here](http://hints.macworld.com/dlfiles/spotlight_cmds.pdf) is great pdf with a list of search attributes and other hints.

Comment: Awesome resource at http://hints.macworld.com/dlfiles/spotlight_cmds.pdf - cheers and thanks for that!

Answer (score 0):

Building on [@mateusz-szlosek's answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/175342/14242):

in your `.bash_profile`, add the following two helper functions:

```
# search below current dir. syntax: f queryterm
f()
{
     mdfind -onlyin . "$2" 
}
# search below current dir, with extension. Syntax: f2 extension queryterm (e.g. f2 py hello)
f2()
{
     mdfind -onlyin . "$2" kMDItemFSName:."$1"
}
```

You can then search for zip files like this:

```
f2 zip blabla
```