# mac search for file type

Tags: macos, spotlight, search

I am trying to find mp3 and mp4 on my external hd.

I tried to follow these methods here.

[How Can I Search A Specific Type of File in Mac?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/602/how-can-i-search-a-specific-type-of-file-in-mac)

This did not work

```
kind: mp3
kind: mp4
```

This was the only method that would seem to work.

```
find / -iname '*mp4' 2>/dev/null 
find / -iname '*mp3' 2>/dev/null
```

I am using el capitan. After I click the other button the File Extension option does not seem to exist anymore.

```
Start a search with Command+F.
Click on the '+' icon on the far side of the taskbar
Select the type from the 'kind' pull-down menu. Select 'other' and then find 'File extension'
```

I don't see show all or file extension anywhere.

```
Open a Find Window (cmd-f) or do a spotlight search and select "show all"
Hit the little "+" icon (to the right of the 'save' button)
Select File Type as a search criteria and select the correct one.
Rerun the search.
```

This didn't seem to do anything.

```
.mp3
.mp4
```

Comment: So, uh... There's a method that works in your question: what exactly are you looking for?

Comment: @perhapsmaybeharry I would prefer a gui method because I can never remember that command.